# How to convert unknown variable of value 2019-12-31 into date format

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Data = 2019-12-31
```

Don't know the data type of the data variable

**Below query**

```
Select to_date (data, 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual
```

Working as follows

```
Select to_date (2019-12-31, 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual;
```

output is 
Error 
Input value not long enough for date format

Don't say i haven't given single quotes .becoz i cant give single quotes to 'data' in the query

Can u give solution s assuming scenarios where the data comes without single quote or where data is number or date datatype

Comment: Just put quotes around the string date: `Select to_date ('2019-12-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd') from dual;`

Comment: The problem is i cant give quotes  . The value is coming from data

Comment: @GMB  I can't give  single quotes to data Select to_date ('data', 'yyyy-mm-dd')

Comment: Where is `data` actually coming from, and how is it being incorporated into the query? It would be helpful to see the code around that statement, and which language that code is in.

Comment: Use a bind variable in the query to pass your variable from the other (external) program.

Answer (score 0):

```
select to_char(to_date(20191231,'yyyymmdd'),'mm-dd-yyyy') from dual;
```

Convert number to date sql oracle

Comment: Updated the question please check

Comment: thanks for contribution .but u see my point is data is a variable which Is sent by some program to my query . In ur solution u changed the input  if u changed to my input it is not working

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly ...i think you are not sure what you are expectation...which program is sending value to query ? If you are not sure about what data are you receving and you also dont want to convert then what you want to do ?